# If statement withing While loop, trying to make it go from one if to the other until it reaches the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I want it to be able so that if the condition is no longer true it keeps moving through the conditions eventually reaching the condition where the price is too high and the customer leaves.

```
yes_no = input("")
if yes_no == '2':
    trade = True
    while trade:
        if currentPrice < maxPrice - 40 and currentPrice < maxPrice - 16:
            priceIncrease = random.randint(8, 25)
            print(currentName,": ummm, sure i'll raise the price by ",priceIncrease)
            currentPrice += priceIncrease
            #this should always be the very last thing
            earnedMoney += currentPrice #

            trade = False

        elif currentPrice <= maxPrice - 16:                            #Change the '0.9' in future days to make it harder
            priceIncrease = random.randint(8, 25)
            print(currentName,": ughh, i'm not sure.... fine, i'll raise the price by",priceIncrease)

            #this should always be the very last thing
            earnedMoney += currentPrice #

            trade = False 

        elif currentPrice > maxPrice - 16 :
            print("Are you serious?? i know how much this product is worth \n")

            #this should always be the very last thing
            earnedMoney += currentPrice #
            trade = False

        else:
            print("this should never be printed")
            break
```

right now if you run the program it just continues to the next loop because of the

```
trade = False
```

and if i remove it it just keeps printing the condition that originally lands on

Please help this is for a school project and I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying that this type of loop:

```
trade = True
while trade:
    print "In the loop"
    trade = False
print "Past the loop"
```

Is never printing `"In the loop"`.  Is that correct?

Also, it would be helpful to have a runnable example with, for example, `currentPrice` and `maxPrice` set.

For example, I think this works as intended:

```
trade = True
currentPrice = 10
maxPrice = 18
while trade:
    if currentPrice < maxPrice - 40 and currentPrice < maxPrice - 16:
        print "First branch"
        trade = False

    elif currentPrice <= maxPrice - 16:
        print "Second branch"
        trade = False

    elif currentPrice > maxPrice - 16 :
        print "Third branch"
        trade = False

    else:
        print("this should never be printed")
        break
print "After loop"
```

(Also, the first branch of the `if` has some extra logic...`currentPrice < maxPrice - 40` and `currentPrice < maxPrice - 16` aren't really both necessary.)